# RIGIFY ERROR: Bone 'brow_glue.B.L.002': Could not match control node for ORG-brow_glue.B.L.002

Tags: rigging

when I try to generate rig. get this error message .
What can I do ? I don't understand what does it mean ?

RIGIFY ERROR: Bone 'brow_glue.B.L.002': Could not match control node for ORG-brow_glue.B.L.002
Incorrect armature for type 'base_generate'

[image: error image]

Comment: What Blender version and is that the standard Human (Metarig) added from the Add menu? - The reason I ask is that I've never seen a bone connecting the brow.L bones to the brow.T bones. The standard rig simply doesn't have a bone in that position. That's checking all Blender versions from 2.83 to 3.3.

Comment: @John Eason,  Hi ,  Blender version 3.3 , Its simple human meta rig but I press  upgrade face rig .original model .

Comment: It looks as if CGDive has done a tutorial on face rigging in Blender 3+ which talks about the updated face rig so it might be worth going through that tutorial to see if there's anything special you should be doing with it. https://youtu.be/wVISTf93uTA

Comment: very helpful video. thanks a lot.

Comment: He's done a whole series of informative videos about rigging and rigify [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLdcL5aF8ZcJv68SSdwxip33M7snakl6Dx).

Comment: @golgi aygiri Did you figure out an answer to this question, or did you start all over with the rigging process?

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered this error. I was able to solve it using the following method.

**First understanding this error**: When there are multiple bones in a single location, it's important that all the bones be aligned at the location. You can easily identify these bones as concentric circles. Ex: Pelvis Joint, Spine.006 + Face Bone.
Coming to the issue here, The bone brow_glue.B.L.002 is the following bone (shown in the picture), it connects the left eyebrows to forehead bones in Blender 3+ rig
[image]

As you can see there are 3 concentric circles at the top and 2 concentric circles at the bottom. The error states that the bottom bones or roots aren't aligned.

**Solution**: Select the bone **brow.B.L.001** (it's to down an left to the joining bone). Go to the Bone Properties tab and copy the Tail Transform values (X,Y,Z).[image: Tail Transform of the adjacent bone]

Select the bone **brow_glue.B.L.002**, Go to the Bone Properties tab and paste the values in Head Transform (X,Y,Z). Repeat similar to the mirror bone on the right side (if you haven't checked X-Axis Mirror option while editing). Come out of edit mode and Go to Bone Data tab and click Re-Generate rig. It should work.
[image: Pasted values in Head Transform of the joint bone]

**Basically align the joints, wherever multiple bones are involved**
Hope this helps :)